# SQL query to calculate percentage in between two dates

Tags: sql, percentage, date-difference

I want to calculate percentage between two dates. Given below table shows values of two days count. Dates are reading from two text boxes (txtStart and txtEnd).

```
slNo  productName  count1  count2
....  ...........  .....   ......
1     A             50      20
2     B             30      39
3     C             20      23
4     D             15      34
5     E             18      45
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT  slNo  
        productName  
        count1, count2
        cast((count1* 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day, @start, @end) * 250)) AS  
        Percentage1, cast((count2* 100.0) / (DATEDIFF(day, @start, @end) 
        * 250)) AS Percentage2 FROM  dbo.tblPercentage
```

While using the above query I am getting one error. the error is : `"Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'"`

How can I get the date difference and apply into the above sql query.

count 250 per day is calculated as 100%. The above table is showing two days count. So 2*250 is consider as 100%. If 3 days count, then it will be 3*250.
So help me to calculate percentage using sql query. Thank you

Comment: No. 10%, because the above table showing two days value. So we have to calculate the percentage using 2*250.

Comment: @Reshma you want to get total days from two dates (start date,end date)?

Comment: @KhurramAli :No. I want to get total count of product between two dates. That I have calculated and stored above table. No I want to calculate the percentage of that count based on the dade difference*250

Comment: @KhurramAli : I have updated my question. I am getting new error. Help me please.

Comment: @Reshma what are count1 ,count2  columns>?

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for this if i understand your problem correctly

```
SELECT  slNo  
        productName  
        count, 
        cast(((DATEDIFF(day,'2014-08-05','2014-06-05') * 250.0) / 250) AS decimal(9, 3)) Percentage1 
FROM  dbo.tblPercentage
```

**Note:** You can replace dates with your startdate and enddate paramters which you are getting from textboxes like this

```
DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate)
```

Comment: @Kuurram Ali : in the above answer, how can I get the percentage of count?

Comment: SELECT  slNo  
        productName  
        count, 
        cast((count * 250.0) / (DATEDIFF(day,'2014-08-05','2014-06-05') * 250.0)) AS decimal(9, 3)) Percentage1 
FROM  dbo.tblPercentage

Comment: @Reshma : If you clearly describe what you really want then i can help you easily

Comment: @Reshma Edit your Question add the necessary details Like your table schema and sample data and what you really want with output sample data ...it would be better if you can provide sqlfiddle